# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 Classic Desktop Missing

Tags: gnome, 14.04, upgrade, gnome-classic

I had recently been running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 with the classic desktop enabled. At the login menu, it would show a few options:

```
    System Default
    GNOME
    GNOME Classic
    GNOME Flashback (metacity)
    GNOME Flashback (compiz)
```

I would select GNOME Classic to login. It would show an interface like the following post: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/07/08/gnome-3-classic-is-more-of-a-hybrid-desktop/

The main features were the Applications / Places menu. When you would hit the super button it would bring up the dash (as well as moving the mouse to the upper right hand corner). The menu would show a favorites and at the bottom it would show Activites.

At the bottom of the screen, the task pane was present.

I've now upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I have the GNOME Flashback metacity/compiz, but I do not have the GNOME Classic. I was really happy with this hybrid interface. Does anyone know how I can bring it back?

Answer (score 0):

After googling much, I found that the panels at the top and bottom of the classic view are called gnome-panel. You can run `gnome-panel` to have them show up. Do Super(aka Start)-Alt-Right-click on them to add, remove panels, or to change properties. The same to add a feature to any given panel, The missing feature you are describing is probably the "Menu bar" item you can add. The task pane is called "Window list" - or you can choose "Window panel"
Another great component to add would be "Indicator applet complete"

It is nearly impossible to figure out how to remove or move what you've added. So here it is: Super(aka Start)-Alt-Right-click on a particular feature you've added, and you'll see a Move/Remove menu. Choose Move and then you can grab that item and move around.

Another useful tip I learned is that in any of those desktops you can run (Alt-F2) `unity` to add unity or `gnome-panel` to add that panel. So you can sort of combine things. Add your addition to the start-up items to make it permanent.